# Getting Firebase SUM of child amount in child income

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I am having problems calculating the `SUM` of income

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String transpo = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Income").getValue());
    //int amount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("amount").getValue()));
    Map<String, String> amount = (Map<String, String>)dataSnapshot.child("amount").getValue();
```

//The model is called income model

```
GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Income>> t = new 

    GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Income>>() {};
            HashMap<String, Income> expenses = (HashMap<String, Income>) dataSnapshot.child("Income").getValue();
```

// Loop through it to get the sum

```
double sum = 0;
            for(HashMap.Entry<String, Income> entry : expenses.entrySet())
            {
                sum += entry.getValue().getIncome();
            }
```

// You have your sum now

```
Log.d(TAG,"Sum= " + sum);
                txt_tzt.setText(transpo);
                txtIncome.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
```

This is my model

```
package Model;

public class Income {




    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public Integer getIncome() {
        return Income;
    }

    public void setIncome(Integer income) {
        Income = income;
    }

    public String getOrganisations() {
        return Organisations;
    }

    public void setOrganisations(String organisations) {
        Organisations = organisations;
    }

    public String getAccount() {
        return Account;
    }

    public void setAccount(String account) {
        Account = account;
    }

    public String getFirekey() {
        return firekey;
    }

    public void setFirekey(String firekey) {
        this.firekey = firekey;
    }
```

//I want to get the total of income pass the value to a hashmap loop and add the new value

```
 private Integer Income;
    private String  Description;
    private String  Organisations;
    private String  Account;
     private String firekey;
    public Income(Integer  Income,String  Description,String Organisations,String Account,String firekey){

        this.Income=Income;
        this.Description=Description;
        this.Organisations=Organisations;
        this.Account=Account;

        this.firekey=firekey;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Vincent. Could you expound as to what seems to be wrong here? Are you getting the wrong value? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @AL.I am getting this error.. java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
                                                                             at com.truth.origicheck.vuma.MainActivity$2.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:103)

Comment: HashMap<String, Income> expenses = (HashMap<String, Income>) dataSnapshot.child("Income").getValue(); this line returns String and not a HashMap.

Comment: @Bijesh...So what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Value event listener,

```
addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int transpo = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                  dreff.child("income");
                    Income income = postSnapshot.getValue(Income.class);
                    transpo += income.getIncome();


                }
```

Let me know how it goes Macharia

Comment: or just show me your json structure and database details and i will be  happy to do it for you

Comment: My Json structure: 
  Description: 
  Income: 
  Organisations: 
  key: 
  usermail: .....,I want to calculate to total income of the child(Like Income1+2+3)etc.....,

Comment: Or what details do you need..., I got this error.com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class Model.Income is missing a constructor with no arguments

Comment: post a screenshot of your database and  your Model Income class